# How to debug a meson.build file?

Tags: debugging, read-eval-print-loop, meson-build

I am learning to code build "scripts" of Meson.

I have been wrote a lot of mistakes in my `meson.build` file, and the only method to check/debug my file is launch `$ meson compile -C build` and get the errors.

It is something like as `debug` (not debug my `.cpp` files the build script) or *"interactive console"* to write line by line the script and test my mistakes.

Comment: I assume you are talking about configure stage errors in your build scripts?

Comment: Yes and check values of variables.

Answer (score 3):

You have two option for that.

1. [message](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual_functions.html#message) : Output will be printed on terminal(stdout)
2. [debug](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual_functions.html#debug) : Output will be printed to file /meson-logs/meson-log.txt